# Getting a column instead of an object when relating with PrimaryKeyRelatedField in Django-Rest-Framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, primary-key

I have a model for applications, which among many attributes have a category. This category is in fact a key to another model that has the category ID, its name, and so on.

```
class Application(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Unknown", null=False)
    .
    .
    .
    category = models.ForeignKey('ApplicationCategory', related_name='applications', null=False, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)


class ApplicationCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
```

Then, on the Django REST serializers side I have the serializer for the applications:

```
class SoftwareSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ApplicationCategory.objects.all())
    
    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ['id', 'title', ... 'category']
```

Which is generating the expected API view, with a dropdown for the categories, but showing them as the ApplicationCategory objects and not giving me their name.

[API showing Category dropdown with objects instead of names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpLQU.png)

Is there a way to access attributes of those objects to show the name in the dropdown, for usability sake?

I have also tried creating a CategorySerializer object (`class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)`) and then using it as `category = CategorySerializer(many=False)` but instead of dropdowns, I get open text fields for the attributes of the category.

Am I trying to do something that is not expected to work?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want exactly, but if you want to retrieve only one field of a related object, consider using [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to define the desired text in  **str** method for your ApplicationCategory class:

```
class ApplicationCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    #example
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.name , self.description)
```

Comment: That's super useful and worked like a charm. There's no need to dig deeper in the model, just make it work like I need.